# Find a closed form for $p$th derivative of $((f\circ g) \cdot g')$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> **Question:** Given that $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are smooth functions, that is, all derivatives of $f$ and $g$ are continuous. Let $p\geq 1$ be a natural number.
>   Find a closed form for 
>   $$((f\circ g) \cdot g')^{(p)}$$
>   where $\cdot$ refers to product and $\circ$ refers to composition.

If $p=1,$ we have 
$$((f\circ g)\cdot g')^{(1)}(x) = f'(g(x))\cdot (g'(x))^2 + f(g(x))\cdot g''(x).$$
If $p=2,$ then 
$$((f\circ g)\cdot g')^{(2)} =$$ 
$$f''(g(x))\cdot (g'(x))^3 + f'(g(x)) \cdot  2 \cdot (g'(x)) \cdot g''(x) + f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x) \cdot g''(x) + f(g(x))\cdot g'''(x).$$
I couldn't obtain a pattern on how these derivaties go. 
Furthermore, to compute $p=3,$ I need to apply three terms product rule. 
This will make the formula more difficult to obtain.
Any hint on the pattern or general formula?